# Insert ending foldmarker in vim with variable commentstring

Tags: vim, folding

I defined two macros for quickly inserting foldmarkers in Vim:

```
nnoremap <leader>mb A {{{<Esc>0
nnoremap <leader>me o# }}}<Esc>0zc
```

but quickly found them to be rather unsatisfying for everything that doesn’t use `#` as commentstring.

So I came up with this to do it dynamically, but it doesn’t work:

```
nnoremap <leader>mb A {{{<Esc>0
nnoremap <leader>me :call s:InsertFoldEnding()

…

function! s:InsertFoldEnding()
  l:line=call line('.')
  l:str=&commentstring + '}}}'
  call append(l:line, l:str)
endfunction
```

Error message:

```
E81: Using <SID> not in a script context
```

What’s the problem? And is there a better method to insert these folds?

#### Clarification:

I want the fold to look like this in the end:

```
" Caption {{{
Content
" }}}
```

Comment: why not using `zf` for creating fold?

Comment: Because all that does is append `"{{{` and `"}}}` to the ends of the first and last line. Which is kind of not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

You have a big bunch of errors.

1. “Using <SID> not in script context” is for calling `s:` function. You need to replace `s:` with `<SID>` and be sure to define the mapping in the same file you defined the function. (Or expand the `<SID>` “manually”, but it is rather tricky.)
2. `l:line=…` is a wrong expression for assignment. Use `:let` to assign, and remove `l:` prefix (in function context it is the default one).
3. `&commentstring+'}}}'` will likely result in `0`. `+` is always numeric addition, use `.` to concatenate strings.
4. `append()` function is not doing indentation. Thus you need to prepend `matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')` to your line or do something smarter.
5. `&commentstring` looks like `/*%s*/`. You don’t need to concatenate, you need to use either `printf(&cms, '}}}')` or `substitute()`.
6. Markers are configurable. Use `split(&foldmarker, ',')[0]` in place of `'{{{'` and `split(&foldmarker, ',')[1]` in place of `'}}}'`.

---

I personally use this (*not* directly what you need, at least without some edits):

```
function InsertBlock(foldlevel, ...)
    let line=getline('.')
    if !empty(a:000)
        let text=a:000[0]
    else
        let text=matchstr(line, '\S.*\S\@<=')
    endif
    if empty(line)
        normal! "_cc_"
        let indent=getline('.')[:-3]
    else
        let indent=matchstr(line, '^\s*')
    endif
    let cmsl=split(&commentstring, '%s', 1)
    let [startmarker, endmarker]=split(&foldmarker, ',')
    let left=(indent).get(cmsl, 0, '').startmarker
    if a:foldlevel>0
        let left.=a:foldlevel
    elseif a:foldlevel==0
        let left.='1'
    endif
    let left.=' '.text
    let right=''
    if !empty(get(cmsl, 1, ''))
        let right=' '.cmsl[1]
    endif
    call setline('.', left)
    normal! $
    if !empty(right)
        call setline('.', left.right)
        normal! l
    endif
    if a:foldlevel==-1
        call append('.', (indent).get(cmsl, 0, '').endmarker)
    endif
endfunction
function CloseBlock(foldlevel)
    if a:foldlevel==0
        return
    endif
    let [startmarker, endmarker]=split(&foldmarker, ',')
    let foldstart=search('\V'.escape(startmarker, '\').a:foldlevel, 'bnW')
    let cmsl=split(&commentstring, '%s', 1)
    if foldstart
        let indent=matchstr(getline(foldstart), '^\s*')
    else
        normal! "_cc_"
        let indent=getline('.')[:-3]
    endif
    call setline('.', (indent).get(cmsl, 0, '').endmarker.a:foldlevel.
                \              get(cmsl, 1, ''))
endfunction
nnoremap ,{          o<C-o>:call InsertBlock(foldlevel('.'))<CR><Esc>
nnoremap ,}          o<C-o>:call InsertBlock(foldlevel('.')+1)<CR><Esc>
nnoremap ,[          o<C-o>:call InsertBlock(foldlevel('.')-1)<CR><Esc>
nnoremap ,-          o<C-o>:call CloseBlock(foldlevel('.'))<CR><Esc>

inoremap ,{           <C-o>:call InsertBlock(foldlevel('.'))<CR>
inoremap ,}           <C-o>:call InsertBlock(foldlevel('.')+1)<CR>
inoremap ,[           <C-o>:call InsertBlock(foldlevel('.')-1)<CR>
inoremap ,-           <C-o>:call CloseBlock(foldlevel('.'))<CR>
inoremap ,+           <C-o>:call InsertBlock(foldlevel('.')+1)<CR><CR><C-o>:call CloseBlock(foldlevel('.'))<CR>
```

. Note that this a) transforms non-empty line into a marker with caption looking like `"▶3 Caption` (`{{{` is too fat to use). End markers are used more rare, they look like `"▲3`. Markers with level automatically end all folds with the greater or equal level, thus end markers are not needed most of time.

Comment: I guess I’ll just use your snippet then … no prospect of ever getting vimscript for me (and no desire, either ;) ).

Comment: What’s <SID>? Some sort of builtin?